# Is it possible to get simpler maps in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I don't know about everyone else, but I find the new 3d maps in Skyrim to be difficult to navigate, especially since you can't rotate all around the map or zoom all the way out.  Is it possible to revert to a simpler, 2D map, similar to the ones in Oblivion?

I have the xbox 360 version.

Answer (score 2):

Well, time to pull out that fancy map from the game box ;)  I read it's not a simple paper texture, so might not be so handy to write on it?

Still I envy you! The PC box doesn't get the nice Skyrim notebook, lame. :(

Comment: That's an idea! never thought of that.  At least I can see the whole map, even if I can't use it to fast-travel. LOL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any 2d maps yet. However, you can get rid of the clouds and remove the navigation restrictions with [these modifications](http://www.skyrimnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=145) to Skyrim.ini.

Comment: Sorry, but I should have said this before.  I have the xbox 360 version.  Is it possible to do that for the 360?

Comment: @ewok No, you're stuck with what you get. Unless they were to add it as DLC or an add-on, which is unlikely. Only the PC world may end up getting a mod or something.

Comment: This does make it simpler in two ways -- you can remove the clouds, and you can change the angle so it's directly above the terrain instead of at an angle. Both are very helpful.